# Pandas - How to convert string with spaces to timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a column of date times in the format month day year hour minute second & am or pm, for example: `6 14 2019 6 17 35 AM`. How can I convert this to a correct pandas datetime format, preferably with military time?

Comment: Try `pd.to_datetime(df['datetimes'], format='%m %d %Y %H %M %S %p')`

Comment: @ChrisA I feel it is better using I rather than H :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen i guess depends on OP's actual format, 12 hour or 24 hour... impossible to know for sure without more examples I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep month-day-year sequence, add `dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m %d %Y %I %M %S %p').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Marking as accepted because you gave the conversion and also if I wanted to keep my format. I don't, but it was thoughtful

Answer (score 1):

Check with

```
pd.to_datetime('6 14 2019 6 17 35 AM',format='%m %d %Y %I %M %S %p')
Out[364]: Timestamp('2019-06-14 06:17:35')
pd.to_datetime('6 14 2019 6 17 35 PM',format='%m %d %Y %I %M %S %p')
Out[365]: Timestamp('2019-06-14 18:17:35')
```